# Why does selecting the second use on the lock screen crashes OS?

Tags: lock-screens, 4.2-jelly-bean, nexus-7, crashes

Running 4.2 on a new Nexus 7 with two users setup with individual google profiles. Both have basic setups (a few apps, sign in patterns, no widgets running).

Both profiles having been running fine for a few days, then after a restart (the first time since setting up multiple profiles) every time I select the second profile it crashes and restarts.

Notes:

- I can log in fully with the first user
- I have uninstalled the clock widget (after reading some google posts about it)
- The second the second user profile image is tapped, the system stops, the pattern doesn't appear, I can't move back to the first user, etc

Comment: Can you obtain a logcat of this when it happens?

Comment: @ t0mm13b I've just installed logcat viewer on the primary user (the one that logs in). It appears to be empty, a part from the things I'm doing since logging in. I'm not sure if there is a way to do a log dump from the last 24hrs system wide